# How to evaluate the integral:$l(y)=\int\limits_\beta^\infty \theta\exp(-y\theta)\alpha\exp(-\alpha\theta)\, d\theta$ where $\alpha,\beta,\theta,y>0$

Tags: integration

how to evaluate this integral:
$$l(y)=\int\limits_\beta^\infty \theta\exp(-y\theta)\alpha\exp(-\alpha\theta) \, d\theta$$
where $\alpha,\beta,\theta,y>0.$
Because I find it infinity!
Can anyone help me to evaluate this integral? Thank you.$$$$
I find this solution :$$\left(\left.\frac{-1}{(\alpha+y)^2}\exp(-(\alpha+y)\theta)\right)\right|_{\beta}^\infty-\left.\frac{\theta}{(\alpha+y)}\exp(-(\alpha+y)\theta)\right|_{\beta}^\infty.$$ $$$$
in which in the second term, I obtain infinity value!

Comment: Try substituting $t = exp(-\alpha \theta)$ .

Comment: Hint: Note that $\ell(y) = - \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \int_\beta^\infty \alpha \exp(-(y+\alpha) \theta)\ d\theta$

Comment: @Dilawar Or not.

Answer (score 1):

The product
$$
\begin{align}
x\exp(-x)
&=x/\exp(x)\\
&=x/(1+x+x^2/2+x^3/6+\dots)\\
&=1/(1/x+1+x/2+x^2/6+\dots)
\end{align}
$$
$1/x\to0$ as $x\to\infty$ . Sum of other terms in the denominator $\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$. So the product $x\exp(-x)\to0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: It makes answers easier to read if you use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong, your 2nd term is not infinite ! Indeed [exponential growth is much stronger than polynomial one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth), so $\lim_{x \to +\infty} x.e^{-x} = 0$.

Beware of the $\alpha$ factor inside the integral and signs, I found for my part:
$$
l(y) = \left( \frac\alpha{(y + \alpha)^2} - \frac{\alpha \beta}{y + \alpha} \right) e^{-(y + \alpha) \beta}
$$